# How to change the Monitor brightness on Linux?

Tags: linux, opensuse, brightness, xserver

How do I programmatically change the monitor brightness on Linux?

I'm using SLES 11.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to change screen brightness with c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811279/possible-to-change-screen-brightness-with-c)

Answer (score 31):

You can always use

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.9
```

Comment: "LVDS1" is the name of the display you want to change. Run `xrandr` and check the name of the display you have. The line will look something like "LVDS1 connected 1920x1080+0+0".

Comment: Quote from `man xrandr` regarding `--brightness`: "this is a software only modification, if your hardware has support to actually change the brightness, you will probably prefer to use `xbacklight`"

Comment: change LVDS1 to eDP if you have a laptop, if you have a DP monitor and have it connected with DP, use DP instad, same with DVI1,DVI2 etc

Comment: Amr is right. This can turn all white  to black, or all black to white; but not make the white brigher

Comment: As this answer do not really changes the brightness of the monitor you better try the possibilities from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1181157/1046889

Answer (score 14):

You can try using xbacklight.

`xbacklight -set 100`

Answer (score 4):

On my machine I run the following as root:

```
echo -n 10 > /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Comment: This is what I use, but typing this command each time is a pain, so you might want to add a shell function to your .bashrc file, something like 
`function brightness() {`
`echo $1 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`
`}`

Comment: I got `echo: write error: Invalid argument` when I tried this. You may need to check `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness` first. I turned out that for me max_brightness was 7.

Comment: It works, but brightness 0 only results in a darker screen, not in blank dark screen (like turn off) !!! Any idea why ?

Answer (score 4):

For me it works perfectly with `xbacklight`.
If you for example wish to set up a key binding, you can use

```
bindsym $SUPER+Shift+plus   exec  xbacklight -inc 10
bindsym $SUPER+Shift+minus  exec  xbacklight -dec 10
```

in your window managers config (I use i3) to regulate your screen's brightness level.

I wouldn't recommend `xrandr` for this since it doesn't stop at 100% brightness automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The [ddcutil](https://github.com/rockowitz/ddcutil) application can change an external monitor's actual backlight brightness via the VESA DDC/MCCS standard (xrandr can only move the X11 output within a monitor's currently set limits, it can't change the actual backlight brightness). This should work for any monitors that support that capability via Display Data Channel (DDC has been around for some time, it is be widely supported, but for external monitors only). I use ddcutil to automatically adjust my monitor based on the ambient light level sampled from a webcam.  Ddcutil uses the i2c-dev kernel module (modprobe i2c-dev or set it to load at boot).

```
ddcutil detect                    # Get list of DDC displays
ddcutil --display 2 capabilities  # List VCP feature key numbers
ddcutil --display 2 getvcp 10     # Get brightness by key number
ddcutil --display 2 setvcp 10 50  # Set brightness to 50
```

Comment: Subsequent to answering this question, I have written my own desktop tray GUI front end to ddcutil specifically for quick access to backlight adjustments.  If you need such a tool, see vdu_controls at https://github.com/digitaltrails/vdu_controls or the brief write up at https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/559401-Desktop-control-of-external-monitor-settings-with-ddcutil-and-vdu_controls

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using [xgamma](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xgamma1.html).  Although it's not pure code, at least it's just a command line utility.

Comment: xgamma is not a monitor brightness, it is image filtering before output it into VGA card.

Answer (score 0):

edit `/etc/default/grub` file and add

`“pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor”` after

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
```

after the changes, the whole line will look like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor”
```

Chirag Singh

Answer (score 0):

If you have **multiple** displays and php installed, put this in

/usr/bin/brightness

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
$br=(double)$argv[1];
if(!$br||$br>1) die("enter brightness lvl 0.1 - 1");
preg_match_all('!^(\S+)!m',`xrandr --current | grep ' connected'`,$m);
foreach($m[1] as $display){
        echo `xrandr --output $display --brightness $br`."\n";
}
```

than call `brightness .7`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple step to control brightness in Linux based system

First, you have to know the monitoring screen connected you.

To know this run this command

```
xrandr -q
```

It will give useful information about the screen

[image: screen_info]

( Here my screen connected to eDP, It might be different for your system )

After knowing that run the below command

`xrandr --output eDP --brightness` [0-10]

Replace eDP by your connected screen from the above output.

you can choose normal brightness values from 0.1 to 1.0

Answer (score 0):

command for this:

xgamma -gamma 0.7

Answer (score 0):

Works only for intel, but you can use `xbacklight`. Create a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and then add

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

Reboot, and then you can use `xbacklight -set somevalue`